# Alpha Blending in Metal Not Giving The Expected Results

Tags: xcode, metal, alphablending

I'm having trouble rendering semitransparent sprites in Metal. I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035162/metal-alpha-blending-is-not-working), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981825/replicate-opengl-blending-in-metal), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835537/metal-mtltexture-replaces-semi-transparent-areas-with-black-when-alpha-values-th), and [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66043) on Apple's forums, and several more, but can't quite get it to work, so **please read on before marking this question as a duplicate**.

My **reference texture** has four rows and four columns. The rows are fully-saturated red, green, blue and black, respectively. The columns vary in opacity from 100% opaque to 25% opaque (1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25 alpha, in that order).

On *Pixelmator* (where I created it), it looks like this:

[image]

If I insert a fully opaque white background before exporting it, it will look like this:

[image]

...**However**, when I texture-map it onto a quad in Metal, and render that after clearing the background to opaque white (255, 255, 255, 255), I get this:

[image]

...which is clearly **darker** than it should be in the non-opaque fragments (the bright white behind should "bleed through").

#### Implementation Details

I imported the png file into Xcode as a texture asset in my app's asset catalog, and at runtime, I load it using `MTKTextureLoader`. The `.SRGB` option doesn't seem to make a difference.

The shader code is not doing anything fancy as far as I can tell, but for reference:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

struct Constants {
    float4x4 modelViewProjection;
};

struct VertexIn {
    float4 position  [[ attribute(0) ]];
    float2 texCoords [[ attribute(1) ]];
};

struct VertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 texCoords;
};

vertex VertexOut sprite_vertex_transform(device VertexIn *vertices [[buffer(0)]],
                                         constant Constants &uniforms [[buffer(1)]],
                                         uint vertexId [[vertex_id]]) {

    float4 modelPosition = vertices[vertexId].position;
    VertexOut out;

    out.position = uniforms.modelViewProjection * modelPosition;
    out.texCoords = vertices[vertexId].texCoords;

    return out;
}

fragment float4 sprite_fragment_textured(VertexOut fragmentIn [[stage_in]],
                                         texture2d<float, access::sample> tex2d [[texture(0)]],
                                         constant Constants &uniforms [[buffer(1)]],
                                         sampler sampler2d [[sampler(0)]]) {

    float4 surfaceColor = tex2d.sample(sampler2d, fragmentIn.texCoords);

    return surfaceColor;
}
```

On the app side, I am using the following (pretty standard) blend factors and operations on my render pass descriptor:

```
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add

descriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha

descriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

(I have tried changing the `sourceRGBBlendFactor` from `.one` to `.sourceAlpha` makes it a bit darker.)

---

If I render the image on a **red** background (255, 0, 0, 255) instead, I get this:

[image]

Notice how the top row gets gradually darker towards the right. **It should be the same color all along** since it is blending two colors that have the same RGB component (255, 0, 0).

I have stripped my app to its bare minimum and put a [demo project on Github](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/MetalSpriteDemo); The full Metal setup can be seen in the repository's source code. Perhaps there's something I didn't mention that is causing this, but can't quite figure out what...

---

**Edit:**

As suggested by @KenThomases in the comments, I changed the value of the `MTKView` property `colorPixelFormat` from the default of `.bgra8Unorm` to `bgra8Unorm_srgb`, and set the `colorSpace` property to the same as `view.window?.colorSpace?.cgColorSpace`. **Now, the semitransparent fragments look much less dark, but still not the expected color:**

[image]

*(The top row should be completely 'invisible' against the red background, left to right.)*

---

**Addendum**

I came up across [Apple's docs on using the Shader Debugger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/tools_profiling_and_debugging/resolving_shader_issues_with_the_shader_debugger), so I decided to take a look at what happens in the fragment shader when my app draws one of the top-right fragments of the sprite (which is suposed to be fully-saturated red at 25% opacity).

Interestingly enough, the value returned from the fragment shader (to which alpha blending will be then applied, based on the color buffer's current color and the blend factors/functions) is `[0.314, 0.0, 0.0, 0.596]`:

[image]

This RGBA value seems to be completely unaffected by whether `MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB` is `true`, `false`, or *absent*.

Notice that the **red** component (`0.314`) and the **alpha** component (`0.596`) are **not equal**, although (if I'm not mistaken) **they should be**, for a fully-saturated red with premultiplied alpha.

I guess this means I've narrowed my issue down to the texture loading stage...?

Perhaps I should abandon the convenient `MTKTextureLoader` and get my hands dirty...?

Comment: Does it help to set the view's `colorPixelFormat` to `.bgra8Unorm_srgb`? Does it help to set the view's `colorspace` to `view.window.colorSpace.cgColorSpace`?

Comment: @KenThomases I'm setting the color attachment's pixel format to the value I get from the `MTKView` , which is reported as `.bgra8Unorm` on the debugger. Forcing it to `.bgra8Unorm_srgb` causes a crash when on `setRenderPipelineState()`.

Comment: @KenThomases Wait, I can set it **to the view** and then have it propagate to the color attachment. But it only seems to improve a little.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, it turns out the problem was indeed in the texture loading stage, but not in any piece of code that I could possibly tweak (at least not if sticking to  `MTKTextureLoader`).

It seems that I needed to introduce some changes to the Attributes Inspector of my asset catalog in Xcode (But at least now I get to tag my original question with `Xcode`: One step closer to the bronze badge!).

**Specifically**, I had to change the texture set's **Interpretation** attribute from the default option of *"Colors"* to *"Colors (non-premultiplied)"*:

[image]

Cleary, these asset catalog texture sets where designed with more traditional texture image formats in mind such as e.g. TGA, an *not* PNG (which is officially non-premultiplied, as per the specification).

I somehow expected that `MTKTextureLoader` would be smart enough to do this for me at load time. Evidently, it is not a piece of information that can be reliably read from (e.g.) a PNG file's metadata/header.

---

**Now,** my reference texture is rendered in all its bright glory:

[image]

As a final, more rigorous test, I can confirm that all 4 colors "disappear" over an equivalent RGB background, regardless of the texels' opacities:

[image]